# Why does Date.new not call initialize?

Tags: ruby, inheritance, date

I want to create a subclass of Date.

A normal, healthy, young rubyist, unscarred by the idiosyncrasy of Date's implementation would go about this in the following manner:

```
require 'date'

class MyDate < Date

  def initialize(year, month, day)
    @original_month = month
    @original_day = day

    # Christmas comes early!
    super(year, 12, 25)
  end

end
```

And proceed to use it in the most expected manner...

```
require 'my_date'

mdt = MyDate.new(2012, 1, 28)

puts mdt.to_s
```

... only to be double-crossed by the fact, that the Date::new method is actually an alias to Date::civil, which doesn't *ever* call initialize. In this case, the last piece of code prints "2012-01-28" instead of the expected "2012-12-25".

Dear Ruby-community, wtf is this?

Is there some very good reason for aliasing *new*, so that it ignores *initialize*, and as a result, any common sense and regard for the client's programmer's mental health?

Comment: By whose definition of "good"?

Comment: What's the alternative? If you call civil from initialize, you've allocated an object you don't need.

Comment: Well, it just seems semantically wrong to allocate and initialize an object in the same method. I mean, if `civil` is the de-facto `new`, why not make it call `initialize` in the end? It may be a pure formality in `Date`, but it will allow to extend the class without the need to actually dig through its implementation details. Hence, I wondered, why the decision to alias `civil` to `new` could've been made?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You define `initialize`, but you create the new instance with `new`. `new` returns a new instance of the class, not the result of `initialize`.

You may do:

```
require 'date'

class MyDate < Date

  def self.new(year, month, day)
    @original_month = month
    @original_day = day

    # Christmas comes early!
    super(year, 12, 25)
  end

end

mdt = MyDate.new(2012, 1, 28)

puts mdt.to_s
```

Remark:
@original_month and @original_day are not available in this solution. The following solution extends Date, so you can access the original month and day. For normal dates, the values will be nil.

```
require 'date'

class Date 
  attr_accessor :original_month 
  attr_accessor :original_day
end  

class MyDate < Date

  def self.new(year, month, day)

    # Christmas comes early!
    date = super(year, 12, 25)
    date.original_month = month
    date.original_day = day
    date
  end

end

mdt = MyDate.new(2012, 1, 28)

puts mdt.to_s
puts mdt.original_month
```

But I would recommend:

```
require 'date'

class MyDate < Date

  def self.create(year, month, day)
    @original_month = month
    @original_day = day

    # Christmas comes early!
    new(year, 12, 25)
  end

end

mdt = MyDate.create(2012, 1, 28)

puts mdt.to_s
```

or

```
require 'date'

class Date

  def this_year_christmas
    # Christmas comes early!
    self.class.new(year, 12, 28)
  end

end

mdt = Date.new(2012, 1, 28).this_year_christmas

puts mdt.to_s
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! I ended up overloading the `new` method. It just seems very strange, that the allocation and initialization of the object happen in one method.

Comment: In your `self.create` definition, the instance vars are being set on the class, not the instance. Using `instance_variable_set` on the result of `new` will take care of that; just make sure you still return the instance.